# Making Separate Header Image for Mobile Devices

Tags: wordpress, header, mobile-devices

My Wordpress site [www.rosstheexplorer.com](http://www.rosstheexplorer.com) uses the Penscratch theme.

Does this theme support or is there a plugin that allows me to have a header image specific for mobile devices and one specific for desktops?

My current header images looks small and stretched on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You must change Your markup.

Change Your `<img class="custom-header">` with `<div class="custom-header">` and set conteiner `background` property:

```
.custom-header { background: url(path_to_image) no-repeat;
background-size: cover; }
```

Comment: I have just inserted that code, but unfortunately it is not quiet what I want.

Comment: I want the header image to be a lot bigger on the mobile device.

If you load up www.nomadicmatt.com on your phone the header image takes up the whole screen. That is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok but on this site nomadicmatt.com used `background-image` css property with `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Is this the line you are referring to -

<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="" class="custom-header">

Would I need to change it to 

<div src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="" class="custom-header">

Comment: No You can set style on `div` like this `<div style="background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>); background-size: cover;">`

Comment: So in Additional CSS do I put

 <div style="background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>); background-size: cover;">  </div>

And

.custom-header { background: url("rosstheexplorer.com/cover-photo-1/") no-repeat; background-size: cover; }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136176/discussion-between-ross-symonds-and-htmlbrewery).

Comment: I copy and pasted the following into Additional CSS

Comment: <div style="background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>); background-size: cover;"> </div> 

.custom-header { background: url("rosstheexplorer.com/cover-photo-1/") no-repeat; background-size: cover; }


I got an error message saying 

"Markup is not allowed in CSS."

I tried each line individually and there was an issue with both lines